# Trim text after character for every item in list - R

Tags: r

I am trying to remove the text before and including a character ("-") for every element in a list.

Ex-

```
x = list(c("a-b","b-c","c-d"),c("a-b","e-f"))
```

desired output:

```
"b" "c" "d"     
"b" "f"
```

I have tried using various combinations of `lapply` and `gsub`, such as

```
lapply(x,gsub,'.*-','',x)
```

but this just returns a null list-

```
[[1]]
[1] ""

[[2]]
[1] ""
```

And only using

```
gsub(".*-","",x)
```

returns

```
"d\")" "f\")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but using `lapply` with `gsub`, R doesn't know which arguments are which. You just need to label the arguments explicitly.

```
x <- list(c("a-b","b-c","c-d"),c("a-b","e-f"))
lapply(x, gsub, pattern = "^.*-", replacement = "")
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "b" "c" "d"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "b" "f"
> ```

Comment: (+1) Perhaps change pattern to `^.*-` (or `^\\w-`) to only replace *leading* (single) characters, which might be a bit safer.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a for loop.

```
val<-list()
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  val[[i]]<-gsub('.*-',"",x[[i]])}
val
[[1]]
[1] "b" "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "f"
```